# Slicing into infinitesimal rectangles

Tags: calculus

If we are dividing the graph of the function $f(x)$ into infinitely many thin rectangles of width $dx$,we are considering that the value of $f(x)$ remains constant in that interval?But if that's case then shouldn't all the heights $f(x)$ be the same since they are part of two rectangles?But certainly $f(x)$ is varying.How can we clear this dilemma?

Comment: Don't think about it as infinitesimals. It doesn't work. Think of it as an approximation via sums of rectangles with small width. The actual definition of $dx$ is somewhat inspired by infinitesimals from a historical standpoint, but is not related at all.

Comment: "we are considering that the value of f(x) remains constant in that interval?" what is the basis for such a consideration?

Comment: For sufficiently nice functions, varying the input by an infinitesimal amount (e.g. as we vary $x$ along the base of the rectangle) causes the value of the function to vary, but only by an infinitesimal amount.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
An infinitesimal is a hyperreal which is smaller than any standard real number but greater than 0. Non standard analysis deals with it. Actually the definition of derivative and integral is different in non standard analysis and quite accurate than standard one i.e the one you have seen in your course.
You:-But if that's case then shouldn't all the heights f(x) be the same since they are part of two rectangles?
Answer:-I guess it's a misconception, the actual thing is between f(x) and f(x+dx) all values are considered equal but f(x) is considered different from f(x+dx). In the language of non standard analysis f(x+dx) is infinitesimally closer to f(x) but not equal to it. So if f(x+dx) and f(x) are different so the heights are also different.
The image I linked may help.

Comment: Then $ydx$ is the area of the rectangle.But then doesn't the above small portion on the curve get neglected as you said $f(x)$ and $f(x+dx)$ are different?

Comment: I don't see why it's getting neglected?

Comment: The dx splits the X axis into infinitely many equal parts. f(x),f(x+dx),f(x+2dx).... What we are doing is, multiplying each of that with dx and add all of them up so that we get area of curve(Remember that dx is not a real number so we will get area infinitesimally closer to area of curve.)

Comment: Thanks does that mean we can consider those two areas equal?

Comment: According to standard analysis, the answer is yes.

Comment: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html.             I suggest you to read the differentiation and integration section of this to get a better grasp on intuitive calculus.

Comment: jimjim, we can consider the all the values of f(x) to be constant in the interval f(x) and f(x+dx) and the reason is all hyperreal a between them are much smaller than dx itself. f(x+dx^2) as an example

Comment: Downvoting other answers does nothing to improve yours.

Comment: @RAHUL Is it true that f(x) is constant over interval [x;x+dx] and for x=x+dx we have two values f(x) and f(x+dx)? Thanks.

Comment: @Mike_bb, Yes:)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to find the probability that
a standard normal random variable is in $(0,1).$
That is, $$J = P(0 < Z < 1) = \int_0^1 \phi(x)\, dx,$$
where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal density function.

Divide $(0,1)$ into $m = 5000$ intervals of equal
width. In R, $\phi$ is denoted `dnorm` (without extra parameters). Heights of
neighboring intervals are very nearly the same.

```
m = 5000;  a = 0;  b = 1
w = (b - a)/m                # interval width
g = seq(a+w/2, b-w/2, len=m) # 5000 midpoints
h = dnorm(g)                 # interval heights
sum(w*h)                     # sum of areas
[1] 0.3413447                $ aprx J
```

In R, `pnorm` is the standard normal CDF $\Phi(\cdot),$ so we can compare our
approximation with the exact value. We see that 5000
intervals are enough to get the value of $J$ accurate to seven decimal places.

```
diff(pnorm(c(0,1)))
[1] 0.3413447
```

Midpoints, heights, and areas of the first six (of 5000) intervals are shown below:

```
 head(cbind(g, h, round(w*h, 10)))
          g         h            
[1,] 0.0001 0.3989423 7.97885e-05
[2,] 0.0003 0.3989423 7.97885e-05
[3,] 0.0005 0.3989422 7.97884e-05
[4,] 0.0007 0.3989422 7.97884e-05
[5,] 0.0009 0.3989421 7.97884e-05
[6,] 0.0011 0.3989420 7.97884e-05
```

... And the last six:

```
tail(cbind(g, h, round(w*h, 10)))
             g         h            
[4995,] 0.9989 0.2422369 4.84474e-05
[4996,] 0.9991 0.2421885 4.84377e-05
[4997,] 0.9993 0.2421401 4.84280e-05
[4998,] 0.9995 0.2420917 4.84183e-05
[4999,] 0.9997 0.2420433 4.84087e-05
[5000,] 0.9999 0.2419949 4.83990e-05
```